# Check if webPart is added as fullWidth instead Boxed

Tags: spfx-webparts, react, design

I've a webPart into React that can be added as full-width or not.

My question is:
is possible to check if this webPart was added as full-width or not?

If I check value of manifest, I can understand only if is addable as "full-width", not if is added as full width in a specific moment.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can add a check for manifest value from your webpart context. check for `this.context.manifest.supportedHosts` array within Webpart context, this will give you the array of configurations you have added to make webpart as Full page. You need to check '*SharePointFullPage*' value in `supportedHosts` array

Comment: this not inform me if the web part was "inserted in a page as full width" but only if is "addable" as full width, correct?